# Nginx URL rewrite for api/rest to rest/v1

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-location

Current API end points are like

```
domain.com/api/rest/[actual_module_routing_path, eg. cms/page/home]
```

In the new system this has to be something like

```
domain.com/rest/V1/$1
```

It has to work regardless of HTTP Method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Trying something like this in nginx host config and I couldn't get it working, some help will be really appreciated

```
location /api/rest {
    #Rewrite $uri=/api/rest/ back to just $uri=/rest/V1/$1
    rewrite ^/api/rest/(.*)$ /rest/V1/$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
location ~ /api/rest/(.*) 
{ 
rewrite ^(.*)$ /rest/v1/$1 redirect; 
}
```